How to make sub "array" to aligned with the outer "array" in equation in LaTeX?
How can I align the equal sign in the subarray environment with the equal sign in the outer array environment?
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{r@{}l}
        5+6= & 11\\
        \left.
        \begin{array}{r@{}l}
            111+222=&333\\
            1111+2222=&3333
        \end{array}
        \right\}\\
        22+23 =& 45\\
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


This is just an example. In practice, these curly braces need to be retained. Is there a way to align all the equal signs?

Modified example
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{r@{}l}
        a\leq & 100\\
        \left.
        \begin{array}{r@{}l}
            a\leq &10\\
            b>&7
        \end{array}
        \right\}\\
        \left.
        \begin{array}{r@{}l}
            a\geq& 10\\
            b<&7
        \end{array}
        \right\}\\
        a+b&=c\\
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}



@MIco For example, in that equation, there are main three sub equations, in which the second equation contains two conditions, so these two equations  should be combined together.

@Mico Thanks. I have added a new example. Do you feel it is a actual (but so far undisclosed) production task?

This is obviously a job for nicematrix.

@Mico We are practical-oriented, but we should also be technology-oriented

@egreg May you give an example for this problem by nicematrix?

You can construct the equation alignment first, then pad the braces } on the right using empty arrays.

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % Similar to \begin{align} ... \end{align}
  \begin{array}{ r @{} l }
          a & {} \leq 100 \\
          a & {} \leq 10  \\
          b & {} > 7   \\
          a & {} \geq 10  \\
          b & {} < 7   \\
      a + b & {} = c
  \end{array}
  % Construct inner pair of } right delimiters
  \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
    \mathstrut \\
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
    \end{array}
    \right\} \\
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
    \end{array}
    \right\} \\
    \mathstrut
  \end{array}
  % Construct outer } right delimiter
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
    \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\
    \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
  \end{array}
  \right\}
\]

\end{document}


Another approach is to use the luamathalign package (which requires LuaLaTeX to run). Here I've replced {array} by {aligned} by two reasons: luamathalign doesn't support nested aligning for {array}, and {aligned} works better with sets of equations (spaces around = or < are correct by default).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{luamathalign}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{aligned}
      5+6&=11\\
        \left.
        \begin{aligned}
          111+222\SetAlignmentPoint-2 &=333\\
          1111+2222&=3333
        \end{aligned}
        \right\}\\
        22+23&=45
    \end{aligned}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{aligned}
      a&\leq100\\
        \left.
        \begin{aligned}
          a\SetAlignmentPoint-2&\leq10\\
          b&>7
        \end{aligned}
        \right\}\\
        \left.
        \begin{aligned}
          a\SetAlignmentPoint-2&\geq10\\
          b&<7
        \end{aligned}
        \right\}\\
        a+b&=c
    \end{aligned}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

The result:


Why should luamathalign use lualatex, it is too limited.

luamathalign uses Lua to manipulate alignment points. As far as I understand, it is not possible do do the same by PdfLaTeX.

I'd do like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{NiceArray}{
  @{}    % no padding at the left
  r      % right aligned column
  @{}    % no padding
  >{{}}l % left aligned column with atom at the start
  @{\quad}
}
a &\leq 100 \\
\addlinespace
a &\leq 10  \\
b &>    7   \\
\addlinespace
a &\geq 10  \\
b &<    7   \\
\addlinespace
a+b &= c    \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix.{2-1}{3-2}\}
  \SubMatrix.{4-1}{5-2}\}
\end{NiceArray}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

The \quad spacing is necessary because the \SubMatrix delimiters take no space, as far as TeX is concerned. Also some vertical separation between the blocks seems to add to clarity.

I adopted amsmath strategy of specifying alignment points before relation symbols.

Here is a nicematrix solution. If you want the two examples to line up you can combine them into one array. Otherwise this can be done with some phantom entries.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{NiceArray}{r@{\;}c@{\;}l}
5+6 & = & 11\\
111+222 & = & 333\\
1111+2222 & = & 3333\\
11+22 & = & 333\\[3ex]
a & \le & 100\\
a & \le & 10\\
b & > & 7\\
a & \ge & 10\\
b & > & 7\\
a+b & =& c
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix.{2-3}{3-3}\}
  \SubMatrix.{1-2}{4-3}\}[right-xshift=5pt]
  \SubMatrix.{6-3}{7-3}\}
  \SubMatrix.{8-3}{9-3}\}
  \SubMatrix.{5-2}{10-3}\}[right-xshift=5pt]
\end{NiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

